# Git shows (master|REVERTING) in command bar after reverting

Tags: git, git-revert

Git shows (master|REVERTING) in command bar after reverting my code. How can I get rid off that?

Comment: What "command bar"? Do you mean in the shell prompt? Or if you're using some IDE, please specify which one.

Answer (score 20):

you are in a middle of a revert. you can do any of the following:

```
git revert --continue / --quit / --abort
```

I assume that you mean to do abort and "cancel" the revert

> **--continue**
>   Continue the operation in progress using the information in .git/sequencer.   Can be used to continue after resolving conflicts in a failed cherry-pick or revert.
>
> **--quit**
>   Forget about the current operation in progress. Can be used to clear the sequencer state after a failed cherry-pick or revert.
>
> **--abort**
>   Cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.