# git revert raises a conflict and it is not fixed (constantly shows (master|reverting))

Tags: git, git-revert

This question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765777/git-shows-masterreverting-in-command-bar-after-reverting) but hasn't received a complete answer, so I ask it again.

When I tried to revert one of the commits in my git commit history, a conflict occurred, so I tried to fix that by manually editing the conflicted file. I saved the file (using vim) and came back to git bash. Then I tried to finalise the reverting process by adding and commiting the edited file. But still I see `(master|reverting)` in my prompt (`user@123123 MINGW64 ~/Documents/library/Git/s1 (master|REVERTING)`). I can get rid of `(master|reverting)` by using `git revert --abort` or `git revert --skip` (using these two commands ignore the whole reverting procedure) but when I use `git revert --continue` nothing happens. In this step, when I run `git status`, git shows me the following messages:

```
On branch master
You are currently reverting commit bbcf9a4.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I am curious why this `(master|reverting)` appears in the first place and how I can finalise my reverting process.

Comment: The process should be: adjust file, then add the file, then `git revert --continue`. Can you show us the full terminal output when running commands in the question? (with some `git status` calls where dimmed necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that, after fixing your conflicts, you ended up with an empty stage and a clean work tree.

In other words, you fixed your conflicts by editing back your files exactly how they were before the revert.

Does `git status` gives you the following screen?

```
On branch master
You are currently reverting commit e768305.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

If that is the case, your stage is empty and your work tree is clean; using `git commit` on an empty stage does nothing, as well as using `git revert --continue` (since it does a commit behind the scenes).

You may just skip your revert (with `git revert --skip`, since the stage is empty), or create an empty commit with `git commit --allow-empty` but it would be pretty pointless.

---

To pragmatically stop Git from saying "REVERTING" (and stop being in a "reverting" state), delete the `.git/REVERT_HEAD` file.

Comment: yes, exactly, I received the same screen you mentioned above. Does it mean that after manually editing the conflicted file, the result is the same as the most recent commit?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean and suspect. If you decide to skip the revert, you can check if the files you had to fix are the same before and after skipping the revert.